# this.props.location.state is null when using replaceState in onEnter

Tags: react-router

I have been following the auth-flow example for react-router 1.0.3:

```
var requireAuth = function(nextState, replaceState){
  if(!auth.loggedIn()){
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login');
  }
}

export default (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
    <Route path='/' component={Messenger} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
  </Route>
);
```

When someone is not logged the function replaceState gets executed as expected showing the /login page, but the state:

`{ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }`

Which is supposed to be in this.props.location.state is nowhere to be found. Instead this.props.location.state is undefined.

This seems to be the same issue as:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2768

Would somebody know why is the state not being set?

**Edit**
I tried this.props.history.replaceState and seems to be passing the state with no problems. It doesn't work only when in the onEnter hook.

**Edit 2**
After experimenting and learning more about react, I realised that I was doing server side rendering with react. The replaceState function would fire in the server, and the Router.match function (recommended for server side rendering) would fire:

```
    Router.match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
          res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
          var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RoutingContext, renderProps));
          var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
          res.status(200).send(page);
        } else {
      res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
    }
  });
```

The redirectLocation would be set for '/login', and the renderProps would contain the next state. But apparently when doing a server side redirect, the nextState is not passed along:

`res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)`

If this is correct then the question is how to set a state when server side redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

In the Component. The pathName is in this.props.location.pathname
I got it there.

```
_handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(this.props.location.state); // null ???
    //the above should be changed to 
    console.log(this.props.location.pathname);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked and I get the pathname '/login' instead of the nextState pathname to which I want to redirect after successful login. Do you get a different result?